# Not getting correct number of characters in Marshal.PtrToStructure

Tags: c#, arrays, delphi

I have come up with current c# struct based on [Reading binary file from delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005084/reading-binary-file-from-delphi) and [Proper struct layout from delphi packed record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779443/proper-struct-layout-from-delphi-packed-record)

Now my problem is I am not getting the correct values from the file

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct test {
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 3)]
  string field1;
  ...
}
```

Hers is the delphi record

```
char3 = Array[0..2] of Char;

test = Record
  field1: char3;
  ...
```

Edit:

As I said in the comment on David's answer. The problem is that I am missing parts of the string. After following David's answer which is to use `byte[]` instead of `string`, my code is now working.

Just in case someone stumbled upon this [delphi record to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336389/delphi-record-to-c-sharp), which is a bit confusing since it assumes that the delphi strings are null-terminated.

Also regarding the `StructLayout` `Pack` attribute, just try setting this to 1 even though the Delphi record you are converting doesn't indicate it. If I am missing something regarding `Pack` please correct me in the comment. Thanks

As for my final struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct test {
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
  byte[] field1;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correctness of the code in the question depends entirely on what `Char` is.

- In Delphi 2009 and later, `Char` is an alias to `WideChar` which is a 16 bit type.
- In earlier versions, `Char` is an alias to `AnsiChar` which is a 8 bit type.

So, your code is correct if you are using a version of Delphi earlier than Delphi 2009. Otherwise your C# code should replace `CharSet.Ansi` with `CharSet.Unicode`.

The other difference is that the C# code insists on the array being null-terminated, whereas the Delphi code need not. So if your Delphi code wants to use all three elements as non-null values then you would need to avoid using a `string` on the C# side. It would become:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct test {
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
  byte[] field1;
  ...
}
```

for pre-Unicode Delphi, or

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct test {
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
  char[] field1;
  ...
}
```

for Unicode Delphi.

Comment: Its earlier than 2009, I also tried the CharSet.Unicode just to check maybe it will work. Anyways, the problem is that I am just getting 2 characters for field1 instead of 3.

Comment: Only the string fields have a problem, particularly field1 gets the first 2 but field 5 is missing the first character.

Comment: Ok I will try using byte[]. I already noticed that they are not null-terminated while looking at the file in hex but disregarded it since I read somewhere here in SO that strings should be used. Too bad I did not bookmarked that one. Thanks